# put request works for one api but not for another api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, axios

- I tested with two apis for axios put.
- for one api its working fine where as with another api it throws an error.
- for one api its showing request as options eventhough I gave as put and I am seeing 403 forbidden error
- for this api i am facing the issue  'http:///sports/sportsId',
- I debugged but still I am not able to find the issue.
- is it a back-end issue
- can you tell me how to fix it, providing my code snippet below

```or-tag-here
 savesports = () => {
    console.log("savesports---->");
    console.log(this.state.sports);
    let savesports = this.state.sports;
    savesports.updatedBy = 'xxx';
    savesports.priceRuleDescription = "test description";

    let data = {
      name: "yyyy",
      email: "sda@gmail.com",
      phone: "2321313"
    };
    axios
      .put("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1", data)
      .then(r => console.log("dada", r));

    console.log(JSON.stringify(savesports));

    axios
      .put(
      'http:///sports/sportsId',
      savesports
      // { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
      )
      .then(r => console.log(r))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

    //this.toggleDrawer("right", false);
    this.setState({ right: false });
    this.setState({ snackBarOpen: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ snackBarOpen: false });
    }, 6000)
  };
```

Comment: Amongst other things, 403 could indicate an authentication issue. Have you tried the same URL in the browser to check what happens?

Comment: @WaynePhipps hey I checked in postman there its working fine

Comment: the method name and data variable name  is `savesports`. Try changing the data variable to a different name.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Check if URL is right

I would first check if the URL is right.

Try changing `http:///sports/sportsId` to `http://sports/sportsId` if that's actually the URL you are requesting to.

#### 2. Avoid name confusion

Both the method name and the put data variable name are the same (`savesports`). I would change the put data variable name to something meaningful like

```
let sportsData = this.state.sports;
sportsData.updatedBy = 'xxx';
sportsData.priceRuleDescription = 'test description';
```

#### 3. Check authentication

`403` might also be to auth error. I would check if the endpoint requires any authentication token or headers.